# Setting Up Babel for JSX on Mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs

Trying to set up Babel for React/JSX.

I've set up a package.json file and used NPM to install babel-cli and babel-preset-react.

~~from my package.json file~~

```
   "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react"
    ]
    },
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
  "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
  "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
},
```

"dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5"
  }

I should be able to type (at the command line):

```
$ babel --version
```

and get a result.  Instead, I get:

```
-bash: babel: command not found
```

Any ideas how to fix this? I want to start compiling ES6 JavaScript and JSX to regular JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to install babel globally for it to become available as a bash command.  `npm install -g babel`.

Alternatively to installing it globally the executable will be in the node_modules path. `./node_modules/.bin/babel`

If you're using it apart of webpack or some other build tool your config should be OK.

Comment: Thanks!  I had to use "sudo" with it but it worked.  Also Shift + Command + .  reveals hidden folders like ".bin".

Comment: What's the difference between @babel/cli and babel-cli?